# Returning JSON file with cURL to use data in a HighCharts stock chart

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl, highcharts

I'm trying to get a free JSON source of oil price data into a HighCharts StockChart from a different server with cURL.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;">      
  <?php

    $ch = curl_init('https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/CHRIS/ICE_B1.json');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    ?>  

  <script>      
    $(function () {

      $.getJSON('$data', function (data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
          rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
          },
          title : {
            text : description
          },
          series : [{
            name : name
            data : data
          }
        }]
      });

    });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

But all this does is dump raw JSON into my browser window rather than making a beautiful chart.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check your closing brackets in you javascript, they don't line up

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use PHP `CURL` and jQuery `getJSON` at the same time, I think you are a bit confused.

CURL is executed by the server, and in this way it just prints the results whenever it gets it, it does not even store the result in `$data` because for that you need to initialise curl to wait for response with `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`. If it would save the result in the PHP variable `$data`, this variable is not available in your Javascript, since javascript is executed on the clients machine and not on the server. To fix that you could do

```
<php echo "<script> data = ".$data."; </script>"; ?>
```

Which is not very pretty but would work. However it would still not work with your `getJSON` function because this function expects a url to get json data from and does not expect json data as parameter..

To make the story short, you can just only use the `getJSON` function like below and delete the PHP code and it should work, I think this is all you want.

```
 $(function () {

        $.getJSON('https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/CHRIS/ICE_B1.json', function (data) {
            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


                rangeSelector : {
                    selected : 1
                },

                title : {
                    text : description
                },

                series : [{
                    name : name
                    data : data
                }]
            });
        });

    });
```

Because `getJSON` does exactly what you tried to do with your `curl` function: get the `json` data from the url you provide and store it in a variable called `data`.

Comment: Yes I am confused! I was trying to use cURL because HighCharts said that JSON couldn't go across domains http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/getting-data-across-domains-jsonp . I tried both of your solutions, but all I get is nothing. No errors, and no pretty chart :(

Comment: Aah in that case, put both the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` line and the echo line I wrote in the answer and remove the line with `$.getJSON`.

Comment: Thanks Bas. I've been tinkering and updated my code. I think the cURL was a bit of a side show in the end as you suggested initially! But I'm still struggling a little.